# filter json data to display on the pie chart

Tags: jquery, highcharts, pie-chart

I have a highcharts chart in one of my views and I want the source data to be ajax loaded from a route that returns a json response.

and my json array is like

```
var data= [
      {
        "id": 24,
        "title": "BCOM",
        "start": "2014-08-05 12:59:00 PM",
        "end": "2014-08-05 2:59:00 PM",
        "description": "mcom",
        "DIFF": 120
      },
      {
        "id": 26,
        "title": "MCOM",
        "start": "2014-08-10 12:59:00 PM",
        "end": "2014-08-10 4:59:00 PM",
        "description": "mcom",
        "DIFF": 240
      },
      {
        "id": 29,
        "title": "MCOM",
        "start": "2014-08-11 12:59:00 PM",
        "end": "2014-08-11 8:59:00 PM",
        "description": "mcom",
        "DIFF": 480
      },
      {
        "id": 30,
        "title": "MCOM",
        "start": "2014-08-13 12:59:00 PM",
        "end": "2014-08-13 4:59:00 PM",
        "description": "mcom",
        "DIFF": 240
      }
    ];
```

And my pie chart rendering script is like bellow

```
$.each(data, function (i, point) {
    point.y = point.data;
});
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        plotBackgroundColor: null,
        plotBorderWidth: 1,//null,
        plotShadow: false
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Browser market shares at a specific website, 2014'
    },
    tooltip: {
        pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            allowPointSelect: true,
            cursor: 'pointer',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
                style: {
                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
                }
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        type: 'pie',
        name: 'Browser share',
        data: data
    }]
});
```

The data is not correctly rendering on the pie chart and it is showing everything 0% and with out color and My result is like [image: Pie chart]

Can any one please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Data that you are offering to **series property ( as data attribute )** is in wrong format.

One of the way to provide data to series is using following format.

```
series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            name: 'Browser share',
            data: [
                ['Firefox',   45.0],
                ['IE',       26.8],
                {
                    name: 'Chrome',
                    y: 12.8,
                    sliced: true,
                    selected: true
                },
                ['Safari',    8.5],
                ['Opera',     6.2],
                ['Others',   0.7]
            ]
        }]
```

Please follow this link : http://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-basic

Comment: Actually iam passing the data to data attribute is in correct jsonformat

Comment: Are you talking about data variable?If yes. then Are you sure about your format. It looks weird.

Comment: can you give me solution to filter this data to correctly fit on pie chart

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse your data to achieve correct form, including name/y parameter in the object.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/sbochan/sb1mvtfw/1/

```
var data = [],
    len = dataRaw.length,
    i;

for(i = 0; i<len;i++){
    data.push({
        name: dataRaw[i].title,
        y: dataRaw[i].DIFF
    })
}
```